# mysql friendlist table structure

Tags: php, mysql

I created an app and I want to add the feature that users can add other users to their "friend list".

I dont know how to create a mysql table to store this data, is this a good structure:

A table with 2 rows, one *unique* row "user" and one "friends", and in the friends row I will add the usernames of the friends like "John, Thomas, Sam, Peter".

And when I want to display the friend list, I will just search for the "user" and display all entries from "friends" row.

Comment: Do not store values as a csv list. Read about many-to-many relationship.

Comment: You need only 2 tables, `users[user_id]` and `user_friendlist[user_id, user_id2]` make the combination `user_id`and `user_id2` together unique.

Comment: You just need a table for your users, which includes a unique users id, and a table for friendships with two columns: user_id1 and user_id2. If one person sends a friend request to another user insert a new row with offering users id as user_id1 and the id of the user he wants to befriend as user_id2 into the friendlist datatable. If the friendship get's accepted, insert another row with the data vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution would be to make two tables.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `user_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `friends` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `friend_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

If you want to add a friend just add the unique user id from users table and the person who you want to be friends with on the friends table.

If you want to get all the friends:

```
 SELECT `users`.`username` FROM `friends` LEFT JOIN `users` ON `friends`.`friend_id` = `users`.`user_id` WHERE `friends`.`user_id` = '1' // with specific user id
```

It will return the friends of user_id 1

```
$rs=$conn->query("SELECT `users`.`username` FROM `friends` LEFT JOIN `users` ON `friends`.`friend_id` = `users`.`user_id` WHERE `friends`.`user_id` = '1'");

$arr = $rs->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

foreach($arr as $row) {
  echo $row['username'];
}
```